# No releases in github when using git flow release

Tags: git, github, git-flow

I am using git flow and the release functionality. It is generally working but I am not seeing any tags created for each release. Is that expected? If so, does anyone have a suggestion for the best way to create a git tag for each `git flow release`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you finish a release, it merges the release branch back into master, and tags the release with its name:

```
`git flow release finish RELEASE`
```

If you want to push your tags to a remote master, you'll need to use:

```
`git push --tags remote BRANCH`
```

Related: [git-flow cheatsheet](http://danielkummer.github.io/git-flow-cheatsheet/)